# Why is $ab + bc + c\bar{a} = ab + c\bar{a}$ true in binary?

Tags: boolean-algebra, binary

I was simplifying the equation of a logic gates problem and I realized that `ab + bc + cā` and `ab + cā` followed the same truth table which is the following:

```
-----------------
| A | B | C | S |
-----------------
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
-----------------
```

The problem is that I haven't found any way to get to the simplified expression from the main one by applying boolean algebra procedures. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to illustrate this equivalence is a [Karnaugh-Veitch map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map):

[image]

The "green" term $b c$ can be eliminated, because it is covered by the disjunction of $c a'$ and $a b$.

Comment: Thanks Alex! Very clear explanation. I didn't thought about justifying it through Karnaught's map.